# Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS: Installed with Preseed file , taking to Black Screen after booting

Tags: server, 16.04, preseed

- I am installing Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS on CISCO Server with Non-Interactive installation using Preseed Config file.
- Installation is Success, But After rebooting it is going to Black Screen (After Selecting OS from Boot options).
- I got worried after seeing the black screen. But i have given a macro(ctrl + Alt + F1) to change the terminal, And there login page occurs.
- Every time i boot OS, i have to give a macro to change the terminal. Why i have to do this? After selecting OS from Boot Options, it has to go to login page on same terminal. But it's not happening.
- Please help me to get out of this problem. Here is my preseed file:

[Preseed file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkgUK.jpg)

Thanks,
PR

Comment: instead of a screenshot, please copy'n'paste the preseed file either directly into you question or if it is too long, you can use a pastebin and post the link.

Comment: Preseed file link:   http://pastebin.com/QRQKc0JK

Comment: I may wrong. But i am thinking this is causing because, it is trying to boot desktop version and not finding corresponding drivers. Because I am installing Ubuntu Server. Please correct me and help to fix this problem.

Comment: is there any command to send "Ctrl + Alt + F1" from preseed file ?

Comment: Perhaps this is the console screensaver? Will the login appear if you just hit the ctrl key?

Comment: Login will appear if i press "Ctrl+ALT+F1".

Comment: Do we have any possibility to send "ctrl+alt+F1" in grub ?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are booting into the splash screen login (GUI) instead of the console.

You can fix this by disabling the splash screen in the preseed config:

```
d-i debian-installer/splash boolean false
```

Generally, I also enable verbose boot logging, to see what's starting:

```
d-i debian-installer/quiet boolean false
```